# Gerar URL amigável com Wordpress e PHP (GET)

Tags: php, wordpress, get

Olá! 
Preciso gerar URL amigáveis no Wordpress utilizando método GET em conjunto com o PHP. Eu tenho um banco de dados de eventos cadastrados, e quero gerar URL com o nome do evento ao invés de aparecer o código e o "?cod=".

Por exemplo, ao invés de aparecer www.meusite.com/evento?cod=1
Aparecer algo do tipo www.meusite.com/evento/competicao-de-futebol-entre-amigos

Há algum plugin especifico para isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Não tem como esconder o ID de forma eficiente, se fosse eficiente o proprio site stackoverflow usaria, mas veja o caso da sua pergunta mesmo, tem o ID `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/430647/gerar-url-amigável-com-wordpress-e-php-get`, ficando assim `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/<id>/<descrição>`, a não ser que você escreva um sistema do zero que faça com que paths de URLs sejam "UNIQUE" no banco e use isto no where na query, mas ai seria fazer algo do zero. No proprio wordpress você pode configurar o mode_rewrite sem precisar fazer no htaccess, tem no painel meta (admin)

Comment: Então Guilherme, se houver uma forma de fazer algo assim no Wordpress, por exemplo www.meusite.com/evento/001/competicao-de-futebol-entre-amigos já ficaria melhor do que utilizar ?cod=, de forma que eu consiga gerar dinamicamente essas páginas.

Comment: Então veja a resposta que fiz na outra pergunta, é só seguir o exemplo do htaccess, se bem quem em Wordpress é só ajustar no proprio painel (meta login), é bem mais fácil que no htaccess.